# Lenovo IdeaPad y510p - Blank Screen

Tags: 13.10, lenovo, ideapad

I'm trying to install Ubuntu (13.10) on the Lenovo IdeaPad y510p, but all I'm getting is a blank screen after I select Install/Try Ubuntu. Is there any way to fix that? (fn+up has no effect)

EDIT: After removing my second videocard  (appears linux doesn't support SLI, it crashes with second card present) and disabling "quiet" and "splash" it now crashes with "divide error: 0000 [#1] SMP"

Answer (score 0):

**Try this:** locate on your keyboard the key which brightens the screen (it should have a dedicated icon/drawing on the key, it looks like a sun with a small plus nearby), when the screen goes blank(black I guess?), **after** you've selected Install/try Ubuntu, press this key repeatedly and see if the screen clears up. If it does and you can at least see the system starting up(but still remains kind of dark), then just be patient and wait till after the login to press the sun-key again. This time(after login) it should have a greater effect and brighten the screen to its full potential.

Comment: No it's not that (see the update)

Comment: I don't know then